# Load images quicker on a uitableviewcell, downloading from internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dispatch-async

I have an UITableView which is a social timeline for pictures, when I scroll down, it is transparent for a while until it loads the images, but when I scroll down and I scroll back up again, the image has to redownload again which I personally think is a waste and is because I am using reusable cells. Is there anyway to load the images quicker? I am already using `dispatch_async` on high priority.

Comment: Yo should cache these images. Use something like SDWebImage

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) libraries for async image (down)loading that also support caching.

Comment: @jacobsieradzki did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: I found SAMCache on GitHub seems to be very useful